# How can I test my extracts for strength?

Tags: flavor, candy, extracts

I made a couple extracts with Everclear and Buddha's hand and with habanero peppers (not combined).  If I want to make some hard candy with them, how can I rough in how much to use so I don't end up with something either tasteless or inedible?

Answer (score 1):

Mix your extract with sugar in half of the proportion as in your candy recipe and start from there. For instance, if your recipe calls for 1 tsp of vanilla extract and 2 cups of sugar, try 1/16 of a tsp of your extract mixed with 1/4 cup of sugar. Add extract by 1/16 tsp until you get the flavor you want. If you like the flavor after you've added 1/16 of a tsp 3 times, that means you want to use 1.5 tsp in your candy.

Comment: Would you just mix it dry and/or not cook it to melt all the sugar? Making very small batches of hard candy seems difficult.  I suppose I could just mix extract with syrup and slurp that...

Comment: @NickT Nah, you can just mix it with sugar to taste it. You're only trying to get an idea of it, you don't have to be perfect.